# My program is not showing the negative input error in c program

Tags: c, output

The part of the code in the source file where it doesn't show *** INVALID STREET NUMBER *** : error message when a negative number is given, It is directly going to the "Please enter the contact's street name: " after taking the street number. I have tried so many things is't working
please help

the part of the code below

```
void getAddress(struct Address* address)

{

    char yesNo ;
    char NL = 'x';
    do{
    printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
    address->streetNumber = getInt();
   
        while (address->streetNumber < 0){
            printf("*** INVALID STREET NUMBER *** <must be a positive number>: ");
        address->streetNumber = getInt();
        }
    } while (address->streetNumber < 1);


    printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");

    scanf("%40[^\n]", address->street);

    clearKeyboard();

    printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");

    while (NL != '\n') {

        scanf("%c%c", &yesNo, &NL);

        if (NL != '\n' || (yesNo != 'Y' && yesNo != 'y' && yesNo != 'N' && yesNo != 'n')) {

            clearKeyboard();

            NL = 'X';

            printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");

        }

    }



    // scanf("%c%*c", &yesNo); 

    if (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y'){
      do{
        printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
              address->apartmentNumber = getInt();
             
                  while (address->apartmentNumber < 0) {

                      printf("*** INVALID APARTMENT NUMBER *** <must be a positive number>: ");
                      scanf("%d%*c", &address->apartmentNumber);

                  }  //clearKeyboard();
      } while (address->apartmentNumber < 1);
    }





    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");

    scanf("%7[^\n]", address->postalCode);

    clearKeyboard();



    printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");

    scanf("%40[^\n]%*c", address->city);

    return;



}


int getInt(void) {
    int value = 0;
    char NL = 'X';
    while (NL != '\n') {
        int k = -1;
        int Nvalue = -1;
        scanf("%d%c", &Nvalue, &NL);
        if (NL != '\n' || Nvalue == k) {
            NL = 'X';
            clearKeyboard();
            printf("*** INVALID INTEGER *** <Please enter an integer>: ");

        }
        else {
            value = Nvalue;
        }
        Nvalue = k;



    }
    return value;
    
}
```

the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqUpz.png)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Does the `getInt` function support reading and returning nevative numbers? Does `address->streetNumber` have signed integer type?

Comment: What is "this"? Additional code should be put in your question as text by [edit]ing that. It shouldn't be posted as comment.

Comment: sorry it's my first time posting here Idk how it works

Comment: You have `int value`, then you go and make another variable, `Nvalue` for no apparent reason, then you return that other one? Why not just use `value`? Why `Nvalue = k`? I have dozens of questions about this unnecessarily complex function to get an int. The way you get an int: `scanf("%d", &value)`. Done. You can also do `fgets()` then `atoi()`.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: The way you design how `getInt` will return the output value is not aligned with how you want to use it in this line `while (address->streetNumber < 0){`. One way is you should change the logic of `getInt` to return a `value < 0 (e.g. -1)` if input from user is considered not valid.